# Unknown number of steps - Training convolution neural network at Google Colab Pro

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run (training) my `CNN` at `Google Colab Pro`, when I run my code, all is allright, but It does not know the number of steps, so an infinite loop is created.

```
Mounted at /content/drive
2.2.0-rc3
Found 10018 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 1336 images belonging to 2 classes.
WARNING:tensorflow:`period` argument is deprecated. Please use `save_freq` to specify the frequency in number of batches seen.
Epoch 1/300
      8/Unknown - 364s 45s/step - loss: 54.9278 - accuracy: 0.5410
```

I am using `ImageDataGenerator()` for loadings images. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iterator does not store anything, it generates the data dynamically. When you are using a dataset or dataset iterator, you must provide `steps_per_epoch`. The length of an iterator is unknown until you iterate through it. You could explicitly pass `len(datafiles)` into the `.fit` function. So, You need to provide steps_per_epoch as shown below.

```
model.fit_generator(
    train_data_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_data_gen,
    validation_steps=total_val // batch_size
)
```

More details are mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit)

> steps_per_epoch: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of
>   samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next
>   epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data
>   tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your
>   dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined.
>   If x is a tf.data dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch
>   will run until the input dataset is exhausted. This argument is not
>   supported with array inputs.

I notice you are using binary classification. One more thing to remember when you use `ImageDataGenerator` is to provide `class_mode` as shown below. Otherwise, there will be a bug (in keras) or 50% accuracy (in tf.keras).

```
train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),class_mode='binary') #
```

Comment: Thank you so much :)