# Model works fine in Keras but not in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

While working with Tensorflow, After fitting the model, in the first epoch it shows unknown (1/unknown) but when using only keras it works fine. What is the problem or am I doing something wrong

Tensorflow code:-

```
import tensorFlow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/train',
                                                 target_size = (150, 150),
                                                 batch_size = 10,
                                                 class_mode = 'binary')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test',
                                            target_size = (150, 150),
                                            batch_size = 10,
                                            class_mode = 'binary')
cnn=tf.keras.models.Sequential()
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=100,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',input_shape=(150,150,3)))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=100,kernel_size=3,activation='relu',))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, activation='relu'))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))
cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
cnn.fit(x=training_set,validation_data=test_set,epochs=10)
```

It shows

```
 Epoch 1/10
    28/Unknown - 12s 416ms/step - loss: 0.9420 - accuracy: 0.4964
```

But after removing tf from every line it works fine

Comment: Sometimes this has happens because the built in version of keras w/ tensorflow is different from the default one you use, i.e. tensorflow.keras =/= keras

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unknown number of steps - Training convolution neural network at Google Colab Pro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61503439/unknown-number-of-steps-training-convolution-neural-network-at-google-colab-pr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are **`ImageDataGenerator`** , the argument, **`steps_per_epoch`** is mandatory in `cnn.fit` while using **`tf.keras`** (not sure how it is implemented in native `keras`)

In the **`Arguments`** section of the [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) for `model.fit` it states:

> **steps_per_epoch**: Integer or None. Total number of steps (batches of samples) before declaring one epoch finished and starting the next
> epoch. When training with input tensors such as TensorFlow data
> tensors, the default None is equal to the number of samples in your
> dataset divided by the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined.
> If x is a tf.data dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch' is None, the epoch
> will run until the input dataset is exhausted. **When passing an
> infinitely repeating dataset, you must specify the steps_per_epoch
> argument**. This argument is not supported with array inputs.

So, if you replace

```
cnn.fit(x=training_set,validation_data=test_set,epochs=10)
```

with

```
batch_size = 20
No_Of_Training_Images = Train_Generator.classes.shape[0]
steps_per_epoch = No_Of_Training_Images/batch_size
cnn.fit(x=training_set,validation_data=test_set,epochs=10, 
steps_per_epoch = steps_per_epoch)
```

the Output will be like:

```
Epoch 1/10
    28/100 - 12s 416ms/step - loss: 0.9420 - accuracy: 0.4964
```